# I'm not sure why my image doesn't render?

Tags: html, css

Could it be because of my background color for the body? Or because I didn't set the image size? or the div container size? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="buildingimage"></div>
 <h2>Quick Links</h2>
<ul id="QL">
    <li><a href="Free_Consultation.html">Free Consultation</a></li>
    <li><a href="Client_List.html">Client List</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="Open_positions.html">Open Positions</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">Latest News</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
body {
font: normal normal normal 75%/1.3em verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans-serif; text-decoration: none; background-color: #fff;
}   


#container {
position: relative;
}

.buildingimage {
background-image: url(hw8_images/building.jpg);
float: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
margin: .5em;

}

#QL {
list-style: circle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your div has width and height is zero, try to add height and width.

```
 .buildingimage {
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg);
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    margin: .5em;

    background-size:cover;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

```css
body {
font: normal normal normal 75%/1.3em verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans-serif; text-decoration: none; background-color: #fff;
}   


#container {
position: relative;
}

.buildingimage {
background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg);
float: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
margin: .5em;

background-size:cover;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
}

#QL {
list-style: circle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="buildingimage"></div>
 <h2>Quick Links</h2>
<ul id="QL">
    <li><a href="Free_Consultation.html">Free Consultation</a></li>
    <li><a href="Client_List.html">Client List</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="Open_positions.html">Open Positions</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">Latest News</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```